# Is there a way to access the key of an object in accordance to its value?

Tags: javascript

I want to access the key of an object in accordance to the value that it was outputted so for example:

I have this object

```
var characters = {
    a: "0",
    b: "1",
    c: "2",
    d: "3",
    e: "4",
    f: "5",
    g: "6",
    h: "7",
    i: "8",
    j: "9"
```

And I have this sum:

```
var result = 2+2
```

The result would be 4 so I would like to output the key e in my console. I've tried to use the method `Object.keys()` but this just returns the key value and it doesn't return it in accordance to the value.

Comment: How about `Object.entries()`?

Comment: Why not just use an array and get the value by index?

Comment: `Object.entries(characters).find(([,c]) => c == 4)?.[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), along with some [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to find the correct key like so:

```js
var characters = {
    a: "0",
    b: "1",
    c: "2",
    d: "3",
    e: "4",
    f: "5",
    g: "6",
    h: "7",
    i: "8",
    j: "9"
}

let value = 2 + 2;

// Use Array.find with == rather than strict equality, since we're comparing numbers and strings.
let [key, val ] = Object.entries(characters).find(([key, val]) => val == value);
console.log("Result key:", key);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) function and [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function like this:

```
Object.entries(characters).find(el => el[1] === result.toString())[0]
```

Comment: `string === number` will always be false!